# getting blank page on phpmyadmin with HHVM

Tags: php, hhvm

I have been trying to run phpmyadmin on HHVM. Usual php files are running properly but whenever I try to access localhost:8080/phpmyadmin it gives me a blank page with no error message. I am assuming it has to deal with mysql. P.S: mysql is already installed on my system.

here is server.hdf

```
PidFile = /var/run/hhvm/pid
Server {
      SourceRoot = /var/www/
      DefaultDocument = index.php
}

Log {
  Level = Warning
  AlwaysLogUnhandledExceptions = true
  RuntimeErrorReportingLevel = 8191
  UseLogFile = true
  UseSyslog = false
  File = /var/log/hhvm/error.log
  Access {
    * {
      File = /var/log/hhvm/access.log
      Format = %h %l %u % t \"%r\" %>s %b
    }
  }
}

Repo {
  Central {
    Path = /var/log/hhvm/.hhvm.hhbc
  }
}

#include "/usr/share/hhvm/hdf/static.mime-types.hdf"
StaticFile {
  FilesMatch {
    * {
      pattern = .*\.(dll|exe)
      headers { 
        * = Content-Disposition: attachment 
      }
    }
  }
  Extensions : StaticMimeTypes
}

MySQL {
  TypedResults = false
}
```

Comment: What version of HHVM are you using? Can you try compiling trunk? Can you try using fastcgi instead of the inbuilt server?

Comment: Any hints in the error log?

Answer (score 8):

Question was long time ago, but maybe this will help someone in the future:

- Open libraries/dbi/DBIMysqli.class.php
- Search for mysqli_real_connect (2 occurrences)
- Typecast the $server_port, i.e. (int)$server_port

At least that worked for me...

Comment: Mine was actually in libraries/dbi/mysqli.dbi.lib.php

Comment: I knew where to look for the error, but I wasn't sure how to correct it! It really helped me!

Answer (score 2):

From the hhvm blog
"6. PHPMyAdmin requires mysqli immediately, and HHVM does not support this.
"

Comment: Good info - I'm using hhvm-fastcgi and I couldn't figure out why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the latest nightly build.  It comes with MySQLi support!
Make sure to restart nginx or apache afterwards and restart hhvm.

NGINX Restart
service nginx restart

HHVM Restart
hhvm -m server

http://hhvm.com/blog/3203/nightly-packages

Answer (score 0):

Here is a radical new solution I stumbled upon....

Install phpmyadmin via apt-get
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin apache2-utils

Restart Apache or Nginx

Navigate to your web directiory, then create a symbolic link to point to the system install path of phpmyadmin.

For example:
ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin phpmyadmin

What is happening here is we are avoiding HHVM altogether when we visit our phpmyadmin folder.  HHVM is only needed for front end usage anyways!

ENJOY